# Is it possible to create sprites from user uploaded images in sitecore?

Tags: c#, ios, sitecore

We are building an sitecore app that is largely image base content.

Currently we are seeing performance slowdown on pages with lots of images on iOS.

Most of our images are in sprites, but user images are currently loaded one by one.

Has anyone come up with a way to generate sprites from images uploaded to sitecore ?

Comment: What about lazy loading images until a user scrolls into view? Or tapping into the `getMediaStream` pipeline to reduce the size?

Comment: I like the way you think ! I had the same idea after posting this, but I'm still curious about the sprites.

Comment: Another option for you is using CDN for your media.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [blog](http://citizensitecore.com/2016/01/18/handling-sprites-in-sitecore-with-svg/) post about how to handle sprites in Sitecore with svg.

I hope it will help you to resolve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some concept work on this topic before, but haven't yet found the time to do a real implementation. But I'll try to share a few of my thoughts on how to do this.

First you have to identify the images that should be in the sprite. This can be done at the page request by traversing the item fields and potentially the related items, or if you have any other logic where you can get this. If the list is static, it would be even better to determine this at publish time. Essentially you need each image guid, width and height. You'll also need to look into what image sizing rules you have. The images in the sprite needs to have a similar width or height in common. Otherwise it would be hard to group them without having large blank areas.

When you have the set of images, you can get the MediaItems and find the information needed to build the html code for the sprite. Essentially the X and Y coordinates where each image will be located in the sprite, so that you can render the html correctly. This would also result in an object that contains all the information to create the sprite. This object can be assigned a guid, that you can use in the image url to request the sprite.

Note that if you're on a multi-server environment, you'll have to look deper into what strategy you want to use for persisting the data about the sprites. You could for example store it in Mongo if you have it, or use a database that is accessible from all content deliver servers. In a multi-server environment the html-request may be on one server and the image sprite request on another server, so it must be possible to retrieve or build the sprite from the information in the image url alone. (This would be best practise in a single server env as well, but it becomes a lot simpler)

Then you'd create an image request handler that gets the sprite object guid, and from the persisted sprite object, it'll get the media items, optionally perform resizing etc, and render those onto a Bitmap. The Bitmap can then be saved as jpg/png and cached on disk (or other suitable service) and returned to the client.

There are of course a lot of different ways to do each part of this and most of it would depend on what data you can put into your sprites (data driven, hand-picked by users on the current item or related items, usage of personalization etc etc), if you can perform pre-calculations of the sprite object and generate the sprite at publish time or if it has to be done render time, what your hosting environment looks like etc etc.

Hope this helps